# Proof for Function Multiplication

Tags: functions

I am trying to solve a problem in an introductory proof based mathematics textbook. I am not entirely sure on how to approach the problem. I am assuming that it has something to do with the inverse of the function $f(x)$ in relation to the fact that $g(x)$ is an even function. I have tried to manipulate it algebraically but continue to run into dead ends. I am also new to this site as well, so if any of you have tips on how to better format my question, feel free to comment.

Given $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ let $g(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{f(x) - 1}$ for all $x$ such that $f(x) \neq 1.$ Suppose that $g(x) = g(-x)$ for all such $x.$ Prove that $f(x)f(-x) =1$ for all such $x.$

Comment: What do you get just by equating $g(x)$ and $g(-x)$?

Comment: $g(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{f(x) - 1}$ and $g(-x) = \frac{-x}{2} + \frac{-x}{f(-x) - 1}.$ Is this correct? I suppose that I could set these two equal to one another because we know that $g(x) = g(-x).$

Comment: @Dawson You're on the right path. Keep going!